# Given a pk value, is there a way to find which tables have a relationship with that specific pk?

Tags: oracle

Let's say that i have a given value of a PK column:

```
10
```

Is there a query to find all tables which have a relationship with that specific pk value?

Answer (score 3):

Example for single column PK.
  PK constraint name can be derived from DBA_CONSTRAINTS (USER_CONSTRAINTS, ALL_CONTRAINTS).
  The code can be extended to multi-column PKs using collection for PK values

```
declare
  p_pk_name varchar2(30):= '<PK constraint_name>';
  p_pk_value varchar2(500):='<PK value>';
  l_cnt int;
begin
  for x in
  (
    select t.owner, t.table_name, cc.column_name 
    from dba_constraints c,
         dba_tables t,
         dba_cons_columns cc
    where c.r_constraint_name = p_pk_name
      and t.owner = c.owner
      and t.table_name = c.table_name
      and cc.owner = c.owner
      and cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name 
  )
  loop
    execute immediate 'select count(1) from '||x.owner||'.'||x.table_name|| ' where '||x.column_name||' = :p_pk_value and rownum <= 1' into l_cnt using p_pk_value ;
    if l_cnt <> 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line(x.owner||'.'||x.table_name);
    end if; 
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a single query, but you could write a PL/SQL block to do it.  You'd start with a query on USER_CONSTRAINTS (or ALL_CONSTRAINTS or DBA_CONSTRAINTS) to find the tables with foreign keys that reference the given primary key.  For each, you'd create and execute a dynamic SQL query to see if there are any rows with the particular PK value you're interested in.

Making it work for multi-column keys would be an additional challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it would look in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @keyColumn VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @keyValue INT 
SET @keyColumn = 'SiteID'
SET @keyValue = 400
SELECT  'SELECT ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TABLENAME, "' + @keyColumn
        + '" FROM "' + TABLE_NAME + '" WHERE "' + @keyColumn + '" = '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @keyValue) + ' UNION ALL'
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU
WHERE   KCU.COLUMN_NAME = @keyColumn
```

I know Oracle has `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, so something similar should work.
I tried with SQLFiddle to adapt it but failed. Perhaps someone else here can edit my answer so it works with Oracle.

Here's what the generated SQL looks like, in part:

```
SELECT 'StockInventory' AS TABLENAME, "SiteID" FROM "StockInventory" WHERE "SiteID" = 400 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SiteDomains' AS TABLENAME, "SiteID" FROM "SiteDomains" WHERE "SiteID" = 400 UNION ALL
```